# ReflectedType of MemberExpression is the base class rather than actual class used

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5.2

So I have a the following classes

```
class Person
{
    virtual string Property{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
class Manager : Person
{
    [SomeAttribute("Hello")]
    override string Property {get;set;}
}
```

If I have a member expression on type Manager, ie:

```
Property prop = PropertyGetter.GetProp<Manager>(p => p.Property)
```

Then the ReflectedType of the `MemberExpression` is `Person`, rather than `Manager`. This means that the `Attribute` information is lost. So:

```
var attribute = prop.GetAttribute<SomeAttribute>();
```

Then `attribute` is null.

I'm assuming this is because the property is from the base class, not defined in Manager, but how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed if I use the `new` keyword on the property rather than `virtual` and `override`.

I think it has to do with the fact that there is no instance of the type `Manager`.

Another way to fix was to change my implementation of `GetProp` to do

```
return typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name)
```

rather than just returning the `property`

Comment: You should consider the implications of shadowing though. Your shadowed property *must* proxy `base.Property` getter and setter. If you don't do this and you happen to pass a `Manager` to a method which accepts `Person` (or upcast `Manager` by any other means), you will potentially lose `Property` information.